# Java Socket: sending and receiveing hashmaps

Tags: java, sockets

I have this **client/server** program where I have to send an E-mail and a password written by the client to the server, but the problem is that I also need to write something along these informations to specify which is the e-mail and which is the password, **to identify them** once in the server side. So I decided to use **hashmaps**, but the problem is that I don't know how to send them via socket (I **have** to use sockets, I literally can't use anything else, if you were wondering).
I usually use the **BufferedReader**, but I've read that it doesn't work with hashmaps, so anyone has any idea?

Comment: *STRONG SUGGESTION*: Send your "list" as XML or JSON text.  EXAMPLE: Serialize the hashmap to JSON before sending; deserialize from JSON upon receiving.

Comment: Just send the email first, password second. You're overcomplicating it.

Comment: @paulsm4 thanks for the suggestion, I've implemented it and it has also helped me reduceing the amount of code lines. thanks again for helping